# How to connect android device to projector?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have galaxy note 2 ( N7100). I want to know is there any way I can give phone output to the projector.

I don't know even, if it is possible.

Comment: prefer this Q. For details


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756450/androidhow-do-i-connect-my-android-phone-to-projector-thru-usb-hdmi

Comment: I know to display by making use of laptop. But I don't want to carry extra burden of laptop.

Comment: Depends on the projector and the Android device: HDMI/MHL could be used if supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As the Samsung Galaxy Note 2 supports MHL for video output, this is possible (with a special cable) if the projector supports MHL input, or with a bigger adaptor if it doesn't. See [my answer on How does MHL work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49447/12442) for more details.

Comment: Do you any affordable projector which support mhl input

Comment: I'm afraid I can't offer a recommendation. Please don't post a new question to ask this, as shopping recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I can't upvote as my reputation is low.