# Connecting android device with PC using HDMI (video recording)

Tags: video, hdmi

I am android game developer, really wanted to capture nice quality video preview of my game for promotion purposes. And my question is, If I would connect by android device (Samsung Galaxy S3 or Nexus 7 tablet: using micro USB HDMI adapter with my PC, like this one for example:

[image]

I know I would be able to see what on my PC what I do on my device, but the point is, would I be able to turn on software responsible for capturing my desktop like Camtasia studio meanwhile to be able to record it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only any use to you if your PC has an HDMI **input**, which is very unusual. You'll only have such a thing if you deliberately bought video capture hardware and attached it to your PC. If you have such hardware, you should use the video capture software that came with it. Trying to use Camtasia to capture it would be like trying to use Camtasia to capture from a webcam.

In addition, depending on what adaptor you use, your video capture hardware may also need to support MHL (the wire protocol used to send video data over the micro-USB and HDMI connectors). See [my answer on How does MHL work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49447/12442) for more details.

Comment: Well I have got laptop with HDMI port, so I believe that`s what you meant, right?

Comment: @Matim Are you sure that's not an HDMI **output**, for plugging the laptop into a monitor or TV? As I say, it's very unusual to have an HDMI **input** on a PC.