# How to view video/photo from smartphone to TV?

Tags: google-play-store, hdmi, chromecast, smart-tv

Is it possible to view media contents from the smartphone to the TV?

I would like to buy a movie from the PlayStore but I am not sure on how to view it.

I need a specific cable (to connect the HDMI port) or is possible to use chromecast too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't say what phone you have, or what Android version, so here's a summary.

## Physical cables

### If your phone supports MHL

and your TV does as well (almost all HDMI TVs do), then you can connect the phone to the TV with an MHL cable. There are two kinds of cables: a standard one, and a special one for certain kinds of Samsung phones. See [How does MHL work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39807/12442) for more details. Usually, the TV *mirrors* the phone screen (i.e. it displays the same thing at the same resolution), but Android offers apps a way to display different content on the TV screen. This is commonly used by media players and presentation apps.

The oldest HDMI TVs don't support MHL, so you'll need a slightly different type of adaptor to connect your phone. You can tell these adaptors because they have an extra input for an external power supply (often a micro-USB socket). Apart from that, it works the same way.

### If your phone supports SlimPort

Some phones use SlimPort instead of MHL, such as the Nexus 4. You can't tell by looking at the phone: both SlimPort and MHL use the USB-on-the-go connector. You have to know which one your phone uses. With the appropriate adaptor, you can connect your SlimPort phone to any HDMI, DisplayPort, or VGA input. Just like MHL, once you've done this the TV screen will mirror the phone screen, or some apps can display different content.

### If your phone supports HDMI

A few phones and tablets have mini-HDMI or micro-HDMI outputs, but this has largely been replaced by MHL and SlimPort. If you do have one of these outputs, you'll need the appropriate cable to connect it to an HDMI input, and just like MHL or SlimPort, it'll mirror the phone screen, or display different content in apps that support it.

## Chromecast

### If you have a Chromecast and Android 4.4 or later

and your TV has HDMI input, then you can use that to mirror the phone screen on the TV wirelessly. Plug the Chromecast into your TV, and use the [Chromecast app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app) to help set it up. As with MHL, Android also offers apps a way to display different content on the TV screen.

### If you have a Chromecast and earlier Android versions

You can still use Chromecast with media player apps that support it, including YouTube, Play Movies, and the Gallery on some devices. You just can't mirror the phone display to the TV.

Comment: I have Nexus4 not rooted with default kitkat 4.4.4

Comment: As I said, the Nexus 4 supports SlimPort, or you can use a Chromecast.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings from SlimPort Support.  The way to connect your device to a TV or display is with a SlimPort HDMI adapter or dock.  There is a new product called the SlimPort NANO.CONSOLE that just launched on Indiegogo – it lets you connect your device to the big screen (at up to 4K Ultra HD 2160p video-out), simultaneously charge your device, and remotely control your device with the included Bluetooth Smart touchpad remote.  It’s really useful and plug-and-play easy to set up and use.  Please check it out on Indiegogo by searching on "NANO.CONSOLE".
You will also want to make sure your device is SlimPort supported.
Thank you!