# Micro Usb to HDMI without MHL

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, hdmi

I've got a cable without MHL adapter. I just want to know How can I connect it with TV.
Of course I've tried much but it was incompatible. Is there any way to make it compatible.
I've Samsung Galaxy S4 and Sony Bravia, Samsung LED on other side![image: Cable]
IF there has to be some signal conversions, can an android app do that ?

Answer (score 2):

To connect your Samsung Galaxy S4 to a TV, you need to use an 11-pin MHL cable. 11-pin MHL cables are usually Y-shaped, and state specifically that they're for Samsung phones.

That's the only way. You can't use a 5-pin MHL cable with this phone. You can't use an app or custom ROM, or any other kind of software on the phone, to get around the need for the right cable.

See [How does MHL work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39807/how-does-mhl-work) for more information.