# Using a phone as a game console- HDMI out and USB in simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth, hdmi, game-controllers, mhl

I have a pico projector, which I use to display HDMI from my Galaxy S3 via an MHL cable. I recently learned that my phone (and most newer Android devices) can be controlled with USB gamepads, mouses, keyboards, etc. with a USB OTG connector, and I have MegaN64 (a very good Nintendo 64 emulator) on my phone, which works great with my USB gamepad.

I'm trying to combine these two features: I want to be able to provide HDMI input to my projector from my phone, and have a USB gamepad controlling it at the same time. Is there any way to do this? I can't with my current equipment, because MHL takes up the micro USB port, so I can't have anything plugged in at the same time. Even if I had a simple micro USB splitter, [as far as I know](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39807/74148) the micro USB port will not work as a USB port and an MHL port at the same time (PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong).

I know there are wireless HDMI receivers available, like Chromecast, but all of them that I've seen use Wi-Fi instead of Bluetooth, and most only work with certain apps, instead of just mirroring the screen. I plan on using this setup while camping, so sending HDMI over Wi-Fi won't be an option for me.

The only close-to-a-solution I've come up with so far is to connect a controller over Bluetooth: there are a good few apps that will connect a phone to a Wii Remote, but that's not the best controller for some of the games I want to play. I've looked into connecting my preferred (USB) controller over Bluetooth, but I haven't been able find a way to do that.

Is there any alternative to MHL for outputting HDMI which doesn't require Wi-Fi, or a way to connect a USB device over Bluetooth?

Comment: do you have a ps3 controler ? or a Bluetouth  game pad ? because I think it is the only good solution

Comment: Yeah, the whole point was to be able to use the controllers I already have, which are all USB. I still haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the already build adapter doesn't work you can make your own folowing this steps (if you are not able to do all the soldering ask a professional nearby like a phone repair shop) :

**Background** : Samsung made the new 11pin MHL technology on the galaxy note 2 and the S3 (those are the first devices to have it any top shelf phone out after that day have that technology ) ,samsung made it specially to sell it's own [Smart Dock station](http://www.samsung.com/nz/business/business-products/business-accessories/business-accessories/EDD-S20HWEGSTD) where you can transform your S3 to a desktop ,the smart dock was (may still) sold to companies only for **100$** , the member @its.mahmud on XDA succeeded to make a clone of that device after reading the source code of the samsung galaxy S3 [see reference](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/accessories/diy-smart-dock-galaxy-s3-t2142357) .

**Now How to build a DIY smart dock :**

**pre-required :**

1. A Micro USB 5 To 11 Pin HDMI HDTV MHL Adapter Converter For Galaxy S3 S III i9300 search for it or get it from [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Micro-USB-5-To-11-Pin-HDMI-HDTV-MHL-Adapter-Converter-For-Galaxy-S3-S-III-i9300/281033844600?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D32474%26meid%3D6b58a3d9b03c4c5cbd2c7124314e9c21%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D190808106400)
2. A 40.2 k ohm resistor (they are sold by lot by you can buy a piece from any repair shop)
3. A USB 2.0 A female to Micro USB B female adapter cable FF (by from near by electronics shop or from [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-2-0-A-fe...-/270798436083) **(if you already have a female USB port somewhere else you can use that instead)**
4. A samsung galaxy s3 under JB stock rom.

**Lets start breaking stuff and making new stuff** :

1. Cut the A Micro USB 5 To 11 Pin open and get the mother-ship this is what it looks like this on the 5pin side:

[image]

2. As you can see in on the ship where it's written `R1` and there is a rectangle around the resistor ,yo need to take off that resistor ,do so.
3. Replace the removed resistor by the 40.2 K ohm resistor.
4. Cut the A USB 2.0 A female to Micro USB B female adapter open to remove the female USB port (if you already have a female USB port somewhere else you can use that instead).
5. Now solder new 4 wires  and shortcut the sense and ground with the 40.2 K ohm resistor as shown is the picture below.

[image]

- Optionally you can cover the wires with duck-tap or any plastic material of your choice.
- You can plug a [USB Hub](http://www.amazon.fr/AmazonBasics-Mini-Hub-USB-ports/dp/B003M0NURK/ref=sr_1_sc_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1437346476&sr=1-2-spell&keywords=USB%20hun%203port) to the female USB port you just made to plug multiple USB devices (mouse and keyboard) or two controllers (android natively detect and use one controller only you need a third party app to manage multiple controllers.
- Now you have a USB or multiple USB ports and An 11 Pin HDMI HDTV MHL to plug on your TV.

**Reference :**

- [Multimedia Dock(I/F: Micro USB 11pin)](http://www.samsung.com/nz/business/business-products/business-accessories/business-accessories/EDD-S20HWEGSTD)
- [DIY Smart Dock tread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/accessories/diy-smart-dock-galaxy-s3-t2142357)
- [Proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFzX6NlKJBU&feature=youtu.be)

**Disclaimer :**

- None Of the component (devices and micro electronics ) used in this unswer are sold by me the links included are here to make it easy to find you can buy them from where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

if your phone supports Both [MHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link) and [USB host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) protocols you can connect both your projector and a USB gamepad **BUT** you gonna need the proper adapter to do that (see figure bellow)

[image]

(***this picture is to show the kind of adapters not to advertise this specific product***)

you can find a lot of those on amazon the price is between 10 -50 $ [here is a link](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/179-4536864-6736719?url=search-alias%3Dmobile&field-keywords=Adapter%20MHL%20HDMI%20%2F%20USB%20%2F%20SD%20for%20Micro%20USB) or you can search for it on the web using this keywords "`Adapter MHL HDMI / USB / SD for Micro USB`"

Comment: if this picture is violating rules of the site let me know I will doodle an adapter instead

Comment: Thanks for the research, but as detailed in the answer I linked to in the question, phones can't use MHL and USB simultaneously- the features lists, user reviews, and instructions on some of those Amazon search results confirm that...

Comment: This is the only way I know ,if you know for sure they can't use both mhl and USB why are you asking for using both ? I think you are wrong about it being impossible the USB and mhl don't use the same protocol they can work both simultaneously but always keep in mind the mini USB port of the android can't provide power you need to feed the adapter with power from an external source...

Comment: The question was more how I could connect a USB device via Bluetooth, or output HDMI without MHL or Wi-Fi. USB and MHL DON'T use the same protocol, but they DO use the same physical connections, which is why they can't both be used at once.

Comment: It can work ,I will think of it more and I will be back to post a more detailed answer and proof that it could work

Comment: I hope so! I'm looking forward to what you discover. Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25761/discussion-between-lord-ralf-adolf-and-michael-hoffmann).

Comment: still don't get why this answer was down voted ! it's one of the ways to do it ,it's well formated and doesn't break any rules

Answer (score 0):

This can be done and it's an amazing thing to pull off. I hoped the connection kit device allows for 5 to 11-pin MHL. If so, that device will allow this to work. This would be perfect for an emulation device and would be cheaper and more powerful than any single board computer like Raspberry Pi.